# How to set value of Json inside array

Tags: json, groovy, ready-api, jsonslurper

I have the following JSON with in an array and when I try to set a value for this JSON, script passes but value isn't set:

```
{
    "langauageCode": "en-US",
    "Test": [{
        "_modificationTypeCode": "added",
        "allocationTypeCode": "3",
        "code": "Test1"
    }]
}
```

My code:

```
def jsonRequest = slurper.parseText(rawRequest)
def builder = new JsonBuilder(jsonRequest)
builder.content.Test.code[0] ='Test2' //Code value is not getting set to 'Test2'
log.info  builder.toPrettyString()
```

Am I not setting the value correctly?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `slurper` is an instance of `JsonSlurper`. If so, there's no need to use `JsonBuilder` at all, since `sluper` returns an instance of a `Map`. So:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def req = '''{
    "langauageCode": "en-US",
    "Test": [{
        "_modificationTypeCode": "added",
        "allocationTypeCode": "3",
        "code": "Test1"
    }]
}'''
def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(req)
slurped.Test[0].code = 'Test2'

println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(slurped))
```